How to use scrapy-playwright to fetch a url after logging in?
I'm trying to access a password protected website and get some specific contents and output them to a csv or json file.  I have a username and password. I'm able to use scrapy-playwright to log in with the following code roughly speaking.
import scrapy
from playwright.async_api import Page
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

async def login(page : Page) -> str:
    await page.wait_for_selector(selector="button[data-automation='signin-btn']")
    await page.locator("button[data-automation='signin-btn']").click()
    await page.wait_for_selector("button[data-automation='sign-in-button']")
    await page.locator("input[name=txtusername]").click()
    await page.locator("input[name=txtusername]").fill("00000")
    await page.locator("input[name=txtpassword]").click()
    await page.locator("input[name=txtpassword]").fill("11111")
    await page.locator(selector = "button[data-automation='sign-in-button']").click()
    return page.url

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    custom_settings = {
        "TWISTED_REACTOR": "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
        "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        "PLAYWRIGHT_PROCESS_REQUEST_HEADERS": None,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://<siteurl>",
            meta=dict(
                      #proxy = "http://localhost:8888",
                      playwright = True,
                      playwright_page_methods = [
                          PageMethod(login)
                      ]),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        pass


Note I had to add      "PLAYWRIGHT_PROCESS_REQUEST_HEADERS": None, to get login inside scrapy to work.  I could probably narrow it down to just the right thing? or maybe I'm doing something wrong.
When I get to this point after I'm authenticated. All I really need to do next is go to a few urls.  specifically "/api/board/casual-board?"  and fetch the json content.  but If I try to do that in my parse() method, I'm getting a 401.   I can continue my navigation to open the next page, and cycle through things like I'm a browser, but then I'm going to have to parse the html from the playwright page, when I've got a perfectly fine json blob of everything I want coming from an api...
ie. If I change my parse method to this after authenticating, I get a 401.
    def parse(self, response):
        parsed_url = urlparse(response.url)
        Path(quote(f"./original/{response.request.method}{parsed_url.path}-{parsed_url.query}")).write_bytes(response.body)

        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://<siteurl>/api/board/casual-board?",
                         meta=dict(
                        playwright = True,
                     )
            callback=self.navigate_to_boards,
        )

    def navigate_to_boards(self, response):
        pass



I tried re-using the playwright_page and still getting it
    def parse(self, response):
        parsed_url = urlparse(response.url)
        Path(quote(f"./original/{response.request.method}{parsed_url.path}-{parsed_url.query}")).write_bytes(response.body)
        page = response.meta['playwright_page']
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = "https://<siteurl>/api/board/casual-board?",
            meta=dict(
                playwright = True,
                playwright_page = page
            ),
            callback=self.navigate_to_boards,
        )

Am I missing something here?

Update:  the second version of the call is missing an Authorization Bearer token generated by the login.  How do I capture that from the login and pass it along with the next requests ?
I figured out how to call await page.context.storage_state(path="./auth/state.json") but how do I get the next request to use it ?

update 2:  I might have found something that works for me. Placing a page.expect_response around the trigger to the click gets me the json response as the body which might be just what I want.   still not sure this is the right way to do this though.
    async with page.expect_response("https://<siteurl>/api/board/casual-board?") as response_info:
        await page.get_by_text("Casual Boards").click()
    response = await response_info.value
    await page.wait_for_selector("[data-automation='navigation-bar-title']")
    return await response.body()   


update 3:
No that's not going to work for me,  I need to actually start spidering at some point and need to fetch / add the access token

update 4:
okay progress.
changing the login button click above to:
    async with page.expect_response("https://<siteurl>/identity/connect/token") as response_info_login:
        await page.locator("button[data-automation='sign-in-button']").click()
    login_response = await response_info_login.value

allows me to capture the authentication token. but now trying to get that out of scrapy is challenging.  changing the return of  the login(page: Page) method to:
    return await login_response.body(),await board_response.body()

and in my parse method putting:
        login_response = response.meta["playwright_page_methods"][0]

is supposed to work but isn't quite.  and also.. how do I adjust the next scrapy request to include the right headers ?    Just straight up playwright I'm trying to do the same thing, but setting extra http headers on the context, and still getting a 426 back. ( so.. missing some headers ? )

update 5.
I was so close...  getting back a PageMethod but wasn't grabbing the result
        login_response, board_response = response.meta["playwright_page_methods"][0].result

is the correct way to fetch that response.
woot. now to figure out the correct .. headers?  to put on the next request to fix my 426 problem
